# Angular Broadcast invoked more than once in $scope

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

I have an application where am using 3 broadcasts, say **broadcast1, broadcast2, and broadcast3.**

**broadcast3** is working fine if broadcast1 and broadcast2 are not broadcasted **before** broadcast3.

But if broadcast3 is triggered **after** broadcast1 and broadcast2 getting triggered, broadcast3 is getting triggered twice continuously.

Please note am broadcasting every broadcasts in **$rootscope** and receiving them on **$scope**. Broadcasting is happening from **parent to child** in all cases.

Please help me in avoiding this continuous twice broadcast

Comment: can you paste your snippet? Most probably value of broadcast1 and broadcast2 is clashing with broadcast3

Comment: could you please share the code snippet for more details.

Comment: Application is tightly coupled that I am unable to detach the code and provide it here. But it may be considered like we have three buttons and 3 broadcasts happening on each click respectively.

Comment: Most likely you are loading the controllers twice. Make sure you don't specify the ng-controller in the view. You should only declare the controller in the route/state -provider config.

Comment: @Marcus: Yes I have taken care that. But still...

Answer (score 0):

There are many advises for your question:

use $rootScope.$emit() instead of $broadcast() - when you broadcast on rootScope, event is bubled down to every scope currently existing. That can be slowing down app. It's not necessary to do that, if your listeners are hooked to rootScope.

Don't forget to clean $rootScope.$on() listeners, when Controller is destroyed. Most people don't do that, which leads to memory leaks:

```js
var listenerCleanFn = $rootScope.$on('ev', cb);

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  listenerCleanFn();
});
```

Comment: But am not receiving the broadcast on rootScope. Am receiving it controller Scope. And I hope '$destroy' would be invoked only on the controller's destroy. But am having all controllers to be live in this case.

Comment: 3rd Broadcast is from parent to child where $emit is not working